# Array sort algorithm on two values. One descending other ascending. Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have the following array structure in Javascript:

```
var unsorted = [
    {h:50,t:70},
    {h:70,t:60},
    {h:30,t:10},    // Ideal Value (Best combination of t being the least and h being the highest )
    {h:10,t:30},
    {h:2,t:10}
]
```

I need to sort it in a way that the value "{h:30,t:10}" colud be on top or at last in the array.

I tried bubble sort but I dont know how I should make it work with two values.

**Bubble Sort:**

```
function bubbleSort(a){
var swapped;
    do{
        swapped=false;
        for(var i=0;i<a.length-1;i++){
            var firstValue = parseInt(a[i].h) ;
            var secondValue = parseInt(a[i+1].h) ;
            if( firstValue > secondValue ){
                var temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[i+1];
                a[i+1]=temp;
                swapped=true;
            }
        }

    } while(swapped);
    return a;
}
```

Any other way than the bubble sort is ok.

Comment: How do you define the best value? Lowest `t` first, then highest `h`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the javascript builtin sort function.

Here's the code where sorted is your new sorted array:

```
var sorted = unsorted.sort(function(a,b) {
    return (a.t-b.t) * 1000 + (b.h-a.h);
});
```

Note that this assumes your numbers in h will not be bigger than 999, or otherwise you will have to increase the multiplier of 1000 to something bigger.

Here's the reference to the javascript sort function: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Comment: Ohh.. Its soo simple and perfect.. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 2):

A better way of doing this would be

```
var sorted = unsorted.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return a.t === b.t ? b.h - a.h : a.t - b.t;
});
```

This way it works for any size of `t` or `h`. (Also fails gracefully for NaN and Infinity).